# Why do I get missing method in the following situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two problems but I'll post them as 2 different questions. Let's start with the first one.

```
class Order < AbstractOrder        
  def update_status
    self.all_created.each do |order|
       order.status = :in_progress    
       order.save
    end  
  end    
end
```

In my specs when I try to call

> Order.update_status

I get an error saying :

```
    Failure/Error: Order.update_status
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `update_status' for #<Class:0x00000103f256a8>
     # ./spec/models/order_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.10439 seconds
3 examples, 1 failure
```

Why? I thought this was a class method not an instance method. If I create an order and do order.update_status it works. What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind the method to the class object you need to define it as `self.update_status`, and the `self` before `all_created` shouldn't be necessary:

```
class Order < AbstractOrder        
  def self.update_status
    all_created.each do |order|
       order.status = :in_progress    
       order.save
    end  
  end    
end
```

Comment: I must blame this on being tired, I thought it was the opposite even after reading multiple answers on this question. Can't believe I got it mixed up...